Extracting data from JSON object by providing path
I am working on a project, where we have to call REST API's. Each API contains user information(name,  email, status etc). Each API has its own response format and we have to extract the data out of it (name, email, status).
Goal of Project: The solution able to parse any API response and get the user data.
Input: mapping
We can input the mapping of response and target fields.
Example:
Response 1:
{
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "users",
            "id": "123",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Test user",
                "handle": "abc.user@test.com",
                "created_at": "2021-03-29T01:30:16.346678+00:00",
                "modified_at": "2023-10-28T00:59:36.404897+00:00",
                "email": "abc.user@test.com",
                "icon": "https://test.com",
                "title": "",
                "verified": True,#true,
                "service_account": False,#false,
                "disabled": False,
                "allowed_login_methods": [],
                "status": "Active",
                "mfa_enabled": False
            }
       }
    ]
}

Response 2:
{
    "data": {
        "userFunctionalPermissions": [
            {
                "userName": "aaa_test1",
                "status": "Active",
                "functionalPermissions": [
                    {
                        "functionalPermission": "Index.AgreeMismatch",
                        "directAssociation": True,#true,
                        "assignedViafunctionalPermissionRole": []
                    }
                ]
            },
]
}
}

response fields: attributes.email   map to target field email
{ "email": "name": "attributes.email" } 
Possible solution:
Using Python and found a package called jsonpath-ng. If we provide the path it able to get the data.
1- First step get the data array
query = parse("data.userFunctionalPermissions[*]")
for match in query.find(Response2_json):
    print(match.value)

2- With the above we will get a single record and can use the json path to find the specific fields.


Challenge:
How to make it robust, so any JSON response can be handled by the code.

What does { "email": "name": "attributes.email" } represent?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I am not sure I understood the question correctly but if the api returns the json as a string the following should work:
import json
# get api
api_result_dict = json.loads(api_result)

alternatively, you can try:
# get api
api_result_dict = api_result.json()

sidenote: the response format is probably {"email":{"name":"attributes.email"}} and not {"email": "name": "attributes.email"}
